# Gerenciar transações no Java EE @Transactional

Tags: java, java-ee, transações

Estou tendo problema ao tentar "herdar" a transação do **Java EE** da minha camada de **serviço** para a camada do **repositório**. A minha intenção é que a transação tenha como escopo a minha função do serviço. Me possibilitando fazer *rollback* caso tenha um erro em sua execução.

Porém, quando eu defino o `@Transactional` do  **repositório** como `Mandatory`:

- Retorna um **erro** falando que **não existe transação ativa**

Quando deixo sem parâmetro, padrão **`REQUIRED`**:

- O **repositório** cria uma **nova transação** quando ocorre um erro
- Não me permite fazer *rollback* das modificações

Como enviar a transação e permitir fazer *rollback* sem problemas usando o **`@Transacional`**?

**Service.class**

```
@Inject
@InstanciaInject
MandadoRepositorio mandadoRepositorio;
@Transactional(rollbackOn = RuntimeException.class, 
                    value = Transactional.TxType.REQUIRES_NEW)
protected void metodoPrincipal() {
    String idPessoa = cookie.getIdPessoa().toString();
    mandadoPagRepositorio.alterarSituacaoMandadoBB(codigoDocumento, idPessoa);
}
```

**Repositorio.class**

```
public class MandadoRepositorio {
    @Transactional(Transactional.TxType.MANDATORY)
    public int alterarSituacaoMandadoBB(String param1, String param2) {
        return criarProcedure("PROCEDURE_NAME")
          .registrarInputOpcionalComValorPorNome("codigo", param1)
          .registrarInputOpcionalComValorPorNome("id", param2)
          .executeUpdate()
          .getUpdateCount();
    }
}
```

**POM.xml**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.transaction-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.ejb</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.ejb-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.2</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.interceptor</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.interceptor-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

---

#### Edição:

- Foi atualizado a classe **MandadoRepositorio.class**
- Não há utilização de Annotations `@Stateless` ou `@Statefull` do EJB

Comment: poderia por gentileza incluir sua classe que faz a chamada para o repositório com os imports? E alguma declaração se houver (`@Stateless`, `@TransactionManagement`...)

Comment: @nullptr eu tentei fiz a edição com o máximo de detalhes possíveis, só modificando os nomes dos métodos e classe. Todas as anotações estão devidamente registradas.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quando você usa `@Transactional(Transactional.TxType.MANDATORY)`, obrigatoriamente você precisa estar com uma transação aberta antes de chamar o método se não você recebe a exceção como você mesmo observou. Você pode ler na especificação do [MANDATORY](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/transaction/Transactional.TxType.html#MANDATORY)

Assim como qualquer método anotado com `@Transactional`, automaticamente vai dar rollback se a exceção lançada for do tipo Runtime, logo você não precisa do parametro `rollbackOn` no seu serviço.

> By default checked exceptions do not result in the transactional interceptor marking the transaction for rollback and instances of RuntimeException and its subclasses do. This default behavior can be modified by specifying exceptions that result in the interceptor marking the transaction for rollback and/or exceptions that do not result in rollback.

Trecho retirado da [especificação](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/transaction/Transactional.html).

Baseado nisso, o que pode estar acontecendo no seu caso, é que a exceção sendo lançada não deve ser "Unchecked".

Tendo uma exceção Unchecked você deveria obter o comportamento esperado "Out of the box"

**EDIT**

Para você usar CDI com `@Transactional`, sua aplicação precisa estar configurada com o `beans.xml` para ativar o CDI. Se você utilizar o atributo `bean-discovery-mode="all"` no `beans.xml` todas as suas classes já serão automaticamente gerenciadas pelo CDI, porém com o escopo `@Dependent` que significa que o ciclo de vida daquele bean está acoplado ao bean que utiliza determinada classe. Logo a principal classe da hierarquia deve estar anotada com algum dos escopos do CDI (`@RequestScoped`, `@Singleton`, `@SessionScoped`, etc).

Configurando suas classes corretamente, você deve obter o comportamento esperado do JTA.

Exemplo do beans.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/…" 
bean-discovery-mode="all"> 
</beans>
```

Agora utilizando as anotações do `EJB`, o container do EJB já gerencia toda a parte de transação para você, sem a necessidade que você utilize a anotação `@Transactional`.

Comment: teoricamente eu tenho uma transação aberta. Já que na minha camada de Serviço eu chamo  `metodoPrincipal()`  e eu a indiquei pra criar uma nova requisição a cada ação. Eu acabei resolvendo a questão utilizando a anotação `@Stateless` do EJB. Mas não dizer ao certo o porquê disso.

Comment: Sua classe com o `metodoPrincipal()` é gerenciada via CDI? 

Quando vc utilizar `@Stateless` todos os métodos não privados se tornam transacionais por padrão, por isso funciona normalmente quando vc anota a classe com @Stateless. Você nem precisa anotar os métodos com `@Transactional` o container EJB cuida disso pra vc. A não ser que vc precise de um controle maior sobre a transação, ai vc pode utilizar as anotações do JTA.